# How do I clean evaporator/drip pan in a Jennair column refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator, cleaning, smell

I have a Jennair column fridge and freezer. Unfortunately, some meat that was defrosting in the meat drawer leaked into the fridge and made its way into and through the two bottom/veggie drawer all the way to (what I believe is) the evaporator or drip pan. Is it possible to clean this and how would I go about doing so?

My fingers are too large to fit in the area with all the small pipes and I don't want to bend or break any of that copper. I tried a small amount of vinegar to clean up the front portion and it worked, but the "mess" goes back behind the fan.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some fridge drip pans can be slid out for cleaning.  That may not be true of this one. Try websearching for an owner's manual?

Comment: Looked at the owner's manual many times. It doesn't list any instructions for this particular area.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 -Spray some kitchen cleaner that will dissolve the stuff, (break up the fat)

Step 2 -wait till it is dry,

Step 3- use a compressed air can and blow it away

Method 2

Use a shopvac (dry/wet) vacuum. Tape a 1/4 inch hose to it and suck up the stuff

Answer (score 1):

- Paper towels, using various things to push them around between the pipes: an old toothbrush, the handle of a wooden spoon, etc.
- A disposable feather duster might do a good job with some spray cleaner.
- There's a gadget they sell at the car wash for $1 to clean a car's A/C vent louvers ... that might work well.  It's like a felt-covered bendy fingery thing.
- A can of keyboard cleaning goop maybe?  Not sure about this.  At's a thick gel that you shove deeply in between the parts of the thing to be cleaned, everything sticks to it, and when you pull it out it somehow stays together and pulls itself out of all the crevices.

Whatever you do, finish with some spray bleach cleaner and leave it to evaporate.